# Tensorflow: When using slim.dataset.Dataset, is there a way to map label ID values to other values?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

```
dataset = slim.dataset.Dataset(...)
provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset, ..._
image, labels = provider.get(['image', 'label')
```

Let's say, for an example in a dataset A, `labels` could be `[1, 2, 1, 3]`. However, for some reason (e.g, due to dataset B), I would like to map the label IDs to other values. The mapping could be like below.

```
# {old_label: target_label}
mapping = {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1}
```

For now, I am guessing two ways:

-- `tf.data.Dataset` seems to have a `map(map_func)` function that every examples should pass, which could be the solution. However, I am more familiar to `slim.dataset.Dataset`. Is there a similar trick for `slim.dataset.Dataset`?

-- I was wondering if I can simply apply some mapping function to a tensor `label` such as:

```
new_labels = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x+1, labels, dtype=tf.int32)
# labels = [1 2 1 3] --> new_labels = [2 3 2 4]. This works.

new_labels = tf.map_fn(lambda x: mapping[x], labels, dtype=tf.int32)
# I wished but this does not work!
```

However, the below didn't work, which is what I need. Could anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [tf.contrib.lookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup):

```
keys = list(mapping.keys())
values = [mapping[k] for k in keys]
table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(
  tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys, values, key_dtype=tf.int64, value_dtype=tf.int64), -1
)
new_labels = table.lookup(labels)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(table.init)
print(sess.run(new_labels))
```